# Find the first line starting with a special symbol in R

Tags: r, string, readlines

I have a set of text files. In each one the useful information starts from the 1st line beginning with !. In the example shown below, useful information starts from line 3.

```
LINES,1
TYPES,T1,I,I,N,T1
!,CODE,GROUP,MTH,COMP
*,1,16,1,"A"
```

However, this first line beginning with ! is located differently in different text files. For example, in another file, the useful information start from line 4.

```
95
LINES,1
TYPES,T1,I,I,N,T1
!,CODE,GROUP,MTH,COMP
*,1,16,1,"A"
```

So I need to find the line number corresponding to this line in each text file. How to do so in R? I tried to use the following code in order to extract the first letter of each row. However, this did not work out.

```
x <- readLines("Test_Case.txt")
First.Letter <- function(x) substring(x, 1, 1)
apply(x, 1, First.Letter)
Error in apply(x, 1, First.Letter) : dim(X) must be positive.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `min` and `grepl` on your lines... You don't need an extra function for starting letter. Use regular expressions to match only the first character.

```
min(grep('^!', c('bla','blub','!test','!2nd')))
```

Or in your case

```
x <- readLines("Test_Case.txt")
important_line <- min(grepl('^!', x))
```